# Cannot locate Authentication_JSON_AppService.axd

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, authentication

I am trying to build a desktop application that uses client application services to authenticate users through an ASP.Net MVC web app. The trouble is I can't seem to get the value for "Authentication service location" correct. It has something to do with the fact that I cannot find Authentication_JSON_AppService.axd when I browse to the default URL which is `http://localhost55555/Authentication_JSON_AppService.axd`.

Please can somebody help me implement this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your web.config:

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL="false"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

Also check your web.config for:

```
 <httpHandlers>
     ....
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate=...
....
```